# Gnome Tweak Tool crashes & forces logout when selecting fonts

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, gtk, theme

I'm trying to change the fonts on my Ubuntu 18.04 system by using `gnome-tweak-tool` and whenever I go to the fonts tab and try clicking on any of the font selection menus, the program will crash and log me out automatically.

I've tried to log it but I literally can't since it logs me out. I'm not sure what the issue is, but if it's any indication of what's wrong, when I installed `gnome-tweak-tool`, I had no `.themes` folder and had to create it manually.

I did `$ sudo apt remove gnome-tweaks` which removes both `gnome-tweaks` and `gnome-tweak-tool`, followed by `$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` as an effort to reinstall the package. Relaunching it again gave the exact same issue.

The output of `$ gnome-tweaks --version` is `3.28.1`, and the output of 
`$ uname -a` gives:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux t420 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

running `Ubuntu 18.04 bionic`

### Edit:

Running `grep -B 50 "tweak" /var/log/syslog | tail -n 50` generates the following:

```
Aug 20 15:05:32 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-
CHANGE above=0 signal=-84 noise=9999 txrate=1000
Aug 20 15:05:32 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 20 15:05:32 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=1000
Aug 20 15:05:35 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=36000
Aug 20 15:05:36 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-83 noise=9999 txrate=108000
Aug 20 15:05:41 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-72 noise=9999 txrate=108000
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 gnome-shell[10862]: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[10862]: **
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[10862]: mutter:ERROR:core/window.c:5296:get_default_window_icon: assertion failed: (default_icon)
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[10862]: == Stack trace for context 0x55b68ecae340 ==
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 gnome-session[10786]: gnome-session-binary[10786]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 6
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 gnome-session-binary[10786]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 6
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10777]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 16544
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10777]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10777]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   69.30  1366 1398 1430 1470  768 771 776 786 -hsync -vsync (47.1 kHz eP)
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 gsd-media-keys[10970]: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 20 15:05:46 T420 gsd-media-keys[10970]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 20 15:05:47 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12533]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Aug 20 15:05:47 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-84 noise=9999 txrate=81000
Aug 20 15:05:47 T420 gnome-shell[12533]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug 20 15:05:47 T420 wpa_supplicant[1103]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-71 noise=9999 txrate=81000
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-shell[12533]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1027]: unreachable code after return statement
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-shell[12533]: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12533]: **
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12533]: mutter:ERROR:core/window.c:5296:get_default_window_icon: assertion failed: (default_icon)
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[12533]: == Stack trace for context 0x563fb8e134b0 ==
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 update-notifier[11777]: Unable to connect to the Notification Watcher: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-media-keys[10970]: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session[10786]: gnome-session-binary[10786]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 6
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session[10786]: gnome-session-binary[10786]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session-binary[10786]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 6
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session-binary[10786]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session[10786]: gnome-session-binary[10786]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session-binary[10786]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-media-keys[10970]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-session-binary[10786]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-media-keys[10970]: Failed to grab accelerators: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.192 was not provided by any .service files (2)
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 kernel: [ 3079.042157] rfkill: input handler enabled
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 at-spi-bus-launcher[9087]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 at-spi-bus-launcher[9087]:       after 3449 requests (3449 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-power[10916]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-xsettings[10947]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-wacom[10951]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-color[10958]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-keyboard[10963]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-clipboard[10953]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-media-keys[10970]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gsd-color[1565]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_LG_Display_oleg_1000
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 update-notifier[11777]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 20 15:05:48 T420 gnome-tweaks[11884]: gnome-tweaks: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

For additional context, I followed the exact same process yesterday of using gnome-tweak-tool and was able to change the fonts just fine without it logging me out or anything, both my desktop and the laptop this issue is on are running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: If you are logged out, it is probably the graphics server that is dying. You seem to be using Wayland. If this is not a deliberate choice you might try choosing gnome on X11 to see if you do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I debugged it by looking through `/var/log/syslog` and figured out that it was related to an icon set I was using, and was able to fix it by replacing the outdated version of the icon set with a more updated version which was only available on GitHub.

The problem came in the fact that I downloaded the icons from the Ubuntu PPA as a package available on a private repo. This version hasn't been updated in the last 12 days that it's been patched, and so I ended up just downloading the source and it worked fine for me

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use 3rd party ppas anymore.